# Remove unwanted files and jars when creating jar with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle

I am pretty new to using Gradle. I am using Gradle-7.5.1. I just want a jar file created using Gradle that contains just the manifest file and the source files I wrote but why does the created jar contain a million other things in it?

My gradle.build file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

version = '1.0'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Manifest-Version': version,
            'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
    }
    baseName = 'MyProj'
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25' < etc >
}
```

What I want in the MyProj-1.0 is:

```
META-INF (holding the Manifest.MF)
com (holding my src files)
```

What I get in the jar is:

```
assets
style
corejava
javax
..and a lot more such things
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers. As I have banged my head to the point of snapping it!

Comment: You're currently creating a "fat jar" instead of a plain jar. Try running `gradle clean && gradle jar` and if that isn't working then try removing the `fatJar` task from `build.gradle` and run those commands again.

Comment: @blacktide Thanks much, I see a lot of improvements with that.